# How can I fetch a NFT's token account (associated account)?

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, metaplex-js, solana-sdk

I am trying to fetch an NFT's token account through Metaplex, and I am not sure which function works. I've tried

```
const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress: nftMint });
```

But that doesn't return the token account.

Any responses are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-get-the-owner-of-an-nft

> If you have the mint key of an NFT, you can find its current owner by
> sneak-peeking at the largest token account for that mint key.
>
> Remember that NFTs have a supply of 1, and they are indivisible,
> meaning that only one token account will hold that token at any point
> in time, whilst all other token accounts for that mint key will have a
> balance of 0.
>
> Once the largest token account is identified, we can retrieve its
> owner.

```
const largestAccounts = await connection.getTokenLargestAccounts(
  new PublicKey(tokenMint)
);
const largestAccountInfo = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(
  largestAccounts.value[0].address
);
console.log(largestAccountInfo.value.data.parsed.info.owner);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I found a much simpler method. Turns out that in Solana's SPL Token Library, there is a function called "getAssociatedTokenAddress". I answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding an answer to this problem:

Turns out Solana's SPL Token Library has a method for this already:
[image]

Here is how I used the code:

```
import { getAssociatedTokenAddress } from "@solana/spl-token";
const tokenAcc = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, this.publicKey);
```